# Android EditTextPreference custom dialog: Add functionality to button

Tags: java, android, preferences

I am trying to add a preference which will store a top level path so that they app can auto-discover some files in that directory on the phone. I have added an `EditTextPreference` and changed the dialog of it so that it has a button as well as a text box.

```
        <EditTextPreference android:id="@+id/etpTopLevelAutoDiscoverPath"
                        android:key="settings_top_level_AutoDiscover_path"
                        android:summary=""
                        android:title="Location to search for custom configurations"
                        android:dialogLayout="@layout/preference_browse_to_path"
                        android:defaultValue=""/>
```

I am struggling however gaining access to the button to add a click listener to it. I think my main problem is that I can't instantiate the custom dialogs view because I don't know when the dialog for `EditTextPreference` is displayed.

This is how I am attempting to set the get the button object but obviously when it gets to creating the button it crashes because the view doesn't exist.

```
        View browseToPathView = this.findViewById(R.id.browseToPathView);
        Button browse = (Button)browseToPathView.findViewById(R.id.btnRootBrowse);
```

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dtg.cinet/com.dtg.cinet.PreferencesScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

I am fairly new to android and have come into a project midway so it is entirely possible that I am just not doing it in the right way but I am fairly stuck at the moment and can't figure out what to do.

Comment: @AkhilJayakumar I don't see how it will be able to help you, it is a pretty obvious error to me personally. But I am probably missing something.